# Pass optional parameter in yml file using PythonScript@0

Tags: python, ado

I wrote a python script which takes multiple arguments. One of those arguments (lets say "argument1" is a store_true argument. So in difference to the other ones I don't have to pass an additional value likes this --argument 2 value2, but only pass --argument1.

So my problem now is that I do not know how to do that within a python script step in a yaml file.

```
- task: PythonScript@0
  inputs:
      scriptSource: 'filePath'
      scriptPath: path/pythonscript.py
      arguments: --argument2 "${{ parameters.value2 }}"
```

In that code sample the argument1 is missing because I dont know how to do that. I need to pass --argument1 IF {{ parameters.argument1 }} (that is an input parameter within an ado pipeline) is true.

Any idea on how to do that?